# php with mp3 header will not load   (update/fixed)

Tags: php, html, header, mp3, embed

test.php code:

```
$fileloc = 'audio.mp3';
header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
header("Content-disposition: inline; filename=$filename");
header('Content-Length:'.filesize($fileloc));

readfile($fileloc);
```

html code:

```
<iframe src="test.php"></iframe>
```

here is the updated code that is working.

thanks hafichuk

if anyone knows a way to do this with

```
<embed> or <object> rather than <iframe>
```

please share your code or send me a link.

Comment: Does [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_soundmidiembed) work in your browser? If not, you need a browser plugin to play the sounds.

Comment: I tested something similar on my local machine and it works - What if you change `ob_flush` to `ob_end_flush` to turn off output buffering?

Comment: sorry i missed that typo... i have flush() and not ob_flush(), but i will experiment with these.

Comment: You can check if output buffering is preventing the file from being sent to output by trying to download the file and checking if the file gets transferred.

Comment: the ob_end_flush() or ob_flush() didn't work for me. can you post the code that worked for you?

Comment: The file path you're loading is a URL. Is the [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) setting enabled?

Comment: i did download the file and it was transfered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your content type to `audio/mpeg3`.

Update 1:

Since it's downloading the file as an attachment, you could also try changing the content-disposition to `header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=audio.mp3');`

The [reference](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/dx/Displaying_files_inline_lc3) I found for this was for `swf` files in the embed tag, however I would imagine that you should do the same.

Comment: My suggestion is to go back and take a look at the http headers the non-php version of the embed tag uses (request and response) and see if there's anything unexpected happening. The only thing I can think of is that `embed` uses a range header and your script might need to do the same.

Comment: You should be able to use Chromes "Inspect Element" or Firefox's Firebug plugin to get the http headers.

Comment: i wasn't able to view much with the inspect element in chrome, but instead of using <embed> i used <iframe src="test.php">. along with your first tip of header('Content-disposition: inline;etc...'). my new problem is posted here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240961/php-with-mp3-header-browser-media-player-cant-determine-length

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I found a simple way to accomplish this, yet it might not be the prettiest, but 
here it is!

test.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['file'])) {
    echo file_get_contents('music.mp3');
    exit;
}
<audio src="test.php?file" controls></audio>
```

You simply extract the file using file_get_contents and output it, using the php file as the sound file, pretty neat :P