# php with mp3 header browser media player can't determine length

Tags: php, header, stream, mp3, mime

test.php code:

```
$path = 'audio.mp3';

header("Content-type: audio/mpeg");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$path.'"');
header("Content-length: ".filesize($path));

readfile($path);
```

html code:

```
<iframe src="test.php"></iframe>
```

this will play the .php as a .mp3, but i will not be able to access the navigation slider in the browser media player. i click on the slider in several different places, but nothing will happen. when i change the source to "audio.mp3" i am able to control the slider again. im pretty sure that it has something to do with the headers. any idea what headers i can use to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually has everything to do with what browser and plugin you are using, "streaming" mp3 or media files for that matter should not be done this way. Use any of the many open source and easy to use Flash players, they handle buffering, controls, display/hidden, and everything for you, for a mp3 file on your server.

Comment: ok... would any of these prevent downloading of the media, or hide the media location?

Comment: Yes, some players have that option.